# QGIS plugin mouseClickEvent

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

I am writing a plugin which shows a graph in a qGraphicsView based on some selected points. I want to be able to read out points clicking in the graph, so I've written a mosePressEvent eventhandler but it does never fire. To test it, I just did

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
      self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage(
                "Success", "Pressed",
                level=Qgis.Success, duration=3)
```

But no matter where I click on the widget, no message is shown. I do neither get any error messages. Do I need to import something or do something else special to make it work?

(The plugin is based on a template by the Plugin builder plugin, maybe I need to remove something)

The entire file is in https://github.com/sickel/qgisSpectre/blob/1beff9842ededc425d3200d566d11dde9c1d3bb7/qgisSpectre.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really more of a IT/ PyQt question, so I will provide an answer in the context of QGIS plugin development, to try to keep on topic.

The reason your `mousePressEvent` does nothing is that you have defined it inside your main plugin class. The `mousePressEvent` method is designed to be re-implemented inside a sub class which inherits from one of the `QWidget` abstract base classes, in this case `QGraphicsView`.

You need to create a new class in your main plugin python file which sub-classes `QGraphicsView` and re-implements the `mousePressEvent()` method. Then create an instance of your subclass and add it to a layout of your dock widget.

I created a simple plugin, based on your `ui` file which just adds the dock widget to the QGIS main window, catches a mouse click event in the graphics view and pushes a message to the message bar showing which mouse button was clicked.

I modified your `ui` file by deleting the `QGraphicsView` object, so we can create an instance of our custom subclass in the `__init__()` method. Then, inside the `initGui()` method, we set its parent to the dock widget, and add it to the `horizontalLayout_2` object.

**the ui xml file looks like this:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>qgisSpectreDockWidgetBase</class>
 <widget class="QDockWidget" name="qgisSpectreDockWidgetBase">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>564</width>
    <height>321</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Spectre &amp;Viewer</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="dockWidgetContents">
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="cbLayer"/>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="cbItem"/>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
      <item>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout"/>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pBCopy">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Copy</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**the contents of the plugin dialog python file:**

```py
import os

from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dock_widget_example_dialog_base.ui'))


class DockWidgetExampleDialog(QtWidgets.QDockWidget, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DockWidgetExampleDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

**And finally, the main plugin python file:**

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QGraphicsView

from .resources import *

from .dock_widget_example_dialog import DockWidgetExampleDialog
import os.path


class DockWidgetExample:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):

        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'DockWidgetExample_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        self.dlg = DockWidgetExampleDialog(self.iface.mainWindow())

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.view = My_Graphics_View(self.iface)
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&Dockwidget Example')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'DockWidgetExample')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'DockWidgetExample')

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):

        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('DockWidgetExample', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            self.toolbar.addAction(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/dock_widget_example/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'Add a Dock Widget'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.view.setParent(self.dlg)
        self.dlg.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.view)

    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&Dockwidget Example'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
        # remove the toolbar
        del self.toolbar

    def run(self):
        self.iface.mainWindow().addDockWidget(Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, self.dlg)
        self.dlg.show()


class My_Graphics_View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        QGraphicsView.__init__(self)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == 1:
            self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage('Left click')
        elif event.button() == 2:
            self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage('Right click')
```

**The result:** after launching the plugin with the icon or from the menu item and clicking inside the QGraphicsView widget, we get a message about which button was clicked pushed to the message bar:

[image]

By the way, I would recommend keeping signal/ slot connections out of the `run()` method and putting them in the `initGui()` method instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I ever could give two points to an answer, this would be the time "The mousePressEvent method is designed to be re-implemented inside a sub class which inherits from one of the QWidget abstract base classes, " was the piece of information I needed to know, but did not find.

Comment: You're welcome @MortenSickel, glad it helped!